# If not compact, does equicontinuity still implies uniform convergence? Any counterexamples?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $S$ is compact, and $L$ is an equicontinuous sequence of functions ($f_n$) over $S$ converging pointwise to a function $f$ at each $x \in S$ and then we can prove that $f_n$ converges to $f $ uniformly over $S$.

My question is why the condition of compactness is important. Can someone give a explicit example showing that it fails if $S$ is not compact?

Comment: $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ with $S = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Could you please show in details why it fails?

Comment: $f_n(x) = x/n\to 0$ pointwise, but $f_n(n) = 1,$ so the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Let be $f$ with support $\subset[0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = f(x-n)$.